# laravel eloquent with sum multiple rows from linked table

Tags: php, mysql, laravel, eloquent

I have a table `Quotes` that has a one-to-many relationship with the `QuoteDetails` table.

The table structure looks like this:

```
return $this->quotes->with('quotedetails')
    ->orderBy('created_at', 'DESC')->paginate(10);
```

Results in:

```
{
   "current_page":1,
   "data":[
      {
         "id":2,
         "subject":"demo",
         "quotedetails":[
            {
               "id":2,
               "quotes_id":2,
               "description":"testing data",
               "total":1080
            },
            {
               "id":3,
               "quotes_id":2,
               "description":"testing",
               "total":180
            }
         ]
      },
      {
         "id":1,
         "subject":"demo",
         "quotedetails":[
            {
               "id":1,
               "quotes_id":1,
               "description":"data",
               "total":360
            }
         ]
      }
   ],
   "per_page":10,
   "prev_page_url":null,
   "to":2,
   "total":2
}
```

I want to include the sum of `quotedetails.total` rather than the full list of `QuoteDetails` rows. I am not sure how this should be done.

Here is how I am querying in my model (`Quotes`)

```
public function quotedetails(){
        return $this->hasMany('App\Models\QuotesDetail', 'quotes_id', 'id');
    }
```

How can i get the `total` sum.

**Here is how i expect the output**

```
{
   "current_page":1,
   "data":[
      {
         "id":2,
         "subject":"demo link data",
         "quotesum": 1260
      },
      {
         "id":1,
         "subject":"demo",
         "quotesum": 360
      }
   ],
   "per_page":10,
   "prev_page_url":null,
   "to":2,
   "total":2
}
```

Answer (score 5, accepted):

```
$query->withCount([
'quotedetail AS quotesum' => function ($query) {
            $query->select(DB::raw("SUM(total) as quotesum"));
        }
    ]);
```

Answer (score 1):

I understand that you want to do it by query, But taking this without even query you'll be able to transform the paginated data this way, giving this example:

```
$quotes = Quotes::whereNotNull('id')->with('quotedetails')
    ->orderBy('created_at', 'DESC')->paginate();

//transform the data in the Paginate instance
$quotes->getCollection()->transform(function($quote){
     $quote->quotesum = $quote->quotedetails->sum('total');
     unset($quote['quotedetails']);
     return $quote;
});
```

The data in the paginated result is transformed and you have what you requested.

> **Pro:** More possibilities to do more with your response without adding any query.
>
> **Con:** More data in the result mean more work on the collection especially in case of large data.

Comment: Wow! this is something new....i never knew i can do this as well! Its really, amazing.

Comment: @user3201500 well, maybe not so new but hardly encountered. Your question was really good, I learnt something new today.

Answer (score 0):

Hi you use eloquent itself to archive this. You can use with sum method to calculate the sum of total column from quotedetails table
`$ideas = Quotes::withSum('quotedetails','total')->with('quotedetails')->all();`